# What happen if fail to allocation memory because of critical memory fragmentation in CMS gc algorithm

Tags: java, garbage-collection

When I set GC algorithm as the CMS, I know it can lead to memory fragmentation.

But I couldn't find any information that what happens in memory when the allocation failed because of the memory fragmentation?

Is it Stop-the world for a long time? or just throw OOME?

I appreciate you

Answer (score 1):

The CMS algorithm uses free lists to record where available space is in the heap.  As you say, over time, the old gen. heap becomes fragmented.  When this reaches a point where the JVM deems it necessary (i.e. it's getting harder and harder to find space for objects) it will perform a full stop-the-world compacting collection.  You may, at this point, experience a significant application pause when this happens.  The length of the pause is proportional to the size of the old generation, not how much live data there is.

You will get an OOM exception if the collector can't reclaim enough space to cope with the rate of promotion of objects from the young generation.

This will also happen with G1, although typically, less often.